# How do I install python packages behind firewall using pip

Tags: python, pip, proxy, firewall

On my work computer, I can browse to pypi.python.org but on my jupyter notebook, whenver I try to pip install a package, I get error. I tried:

```
    !pip install langchain
    or
    %pip install langchain
or
pip install --proxy http://host:port/ langhcain
```

Error (always the same):

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C088C20B50>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/langchain/
```

What can I try or do i need to contact IT sescurity?

```
pip install langchain --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Set proxy environment variables.

set http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy_ip:port
set https_proxy=https://user:password@proxy_ip:port

2.Install Python packages.

pip install package_name

3.As an alternative to steps 1 and 2, you can also pass the proxy to pip directly without setting environment variables for it.

pip install --proxy="user:password@proxy_ip:port" package_name

4.Notice that if you have the pysocks package installed, you can use a socks proxy with pip as well. For example, if you have a socks5 proxy at localhost:1080 you can use it with pipe as illustrated below.

pip install --proxy socks5:localhost:1080 package_name